# Swap partition not used on fresh Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, encryption, swap

My system is freezing when the memory used is maxed out and I was wondering why. Turns out the swap is not being used. Here's my partition table:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63       80324       40131   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda4           81918   909195263   454556673    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       512121690   909195263   198536787   83  Linux
/dev/sda6           81920     3987455     1952768   83  Linux
/dev/sda7         3989504   140705791    68358144   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       492589056   512120831     9765888   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9       140707840   492584959   175938560   83  Linux
```

The swap partition is not turned on and doesn't show in `df` but it does in the disks utility:

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                  392M  1.3M  391M   1% /run
/dev/sda7               65G   19G   43G  31% /
none                   4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                   2.0G   26M  1.9G   2% /run/shm
none                   100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6              1.9G   89M  1.7G   6% /boot
/dev/sda9              166G   47G  111G  30% /home
/home/my-user-name/.Private  166G   47G  111G  30% /home/my-user-name
```

[image]

```
$ sudo swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
```

As you can notice my Home partition is encrypted but I have not encrypted the swap.

Swap seems declared in /etc/fstab:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
#UUID=df55bf68-b824-4f21-83f3-dfa80a0b74ab none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

I'd like to know why it's not working and how can I fix it?

**Update**
It seems there's a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1453738) on this for several releases and has not been fixed for 14.04 yet.

Here's the result of `cat /etc/crypttab`:

```
cryptswap1 UUID=df55bf68-b824-4f21-83f3-dfa80a0b74ab /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

And what was suggested by [A.B.](https://askubuntu.com/users/367165/a-b):

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cryptdisks reload
 * Stopping remaining crypto disks...                                                                    [ OK ]
 * cryptswap1 (stopped)...                   
 * Starting remaining crypto disks...
 * cryptswap1 (skipped, device /dev/disk/by-uuid/df55bf68-b824-4f21-83f3-dfa80a0b74ab does not exist)... [fail]
                                                                                                         [ OK ]
$ sudo swapon -a
swapon: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory
```

Based on [David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster)'s answer I did `cat /dev/disk/by-uuid/` and got 6 uuid's. Did `blkid -U` of each and non is `/dev/sda8` which the swap is supposed to be. I got sda's 1, 5, 6, 7, 9, and `/dev/mapper/luks-****`. The last of which I think is the other encrypted partition that I left untouched during installation (was encrypted by 12.04).

I also tried the following [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/597642/110181). Did not work either.

**Update:**
I ended up reformatting the partitions and re-installing the system. It seems working fine now.

Comment: Check if your swap is declared in /etc/fstab.
If it is not the case, then look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-a-swap-partition-after-system-installation

Comment: @Quentin It seems declared I updated the question.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/crypttab`

Comment: @A.B. just did.

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/cryptdisks reload; swapon -a`

Answer (score 2):

```
cryptswap1 (skipped, device /dev/disk/by-uuid/df55bf68-b824-4f21-83f3-dfa80a0b74ab does not exist)
```

Whatever volume had `UUID=df55bf68-b824-4f21-83f3-dfa80a0b74ab`, when that `/etc/crypttab` entry was generated, doesn't exist any longer.

#### How to fix it

- Run `sudo swapoff -a` just to make sure that all swap spaces are released. The output of `swapon -s` should now be empty (apart from a column header line).
- Remove (or comment out) the lines about swap in `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab`. Make back-ups, if you're unsure.
- You say you want to place swap on `/dev/sda8`. Ignore it's current content for the remainder of these instructions; treat is a garbage data. **You will lose all data on `sda8` in the process! Make a backup, if you value it!**
- Set up a new swap space on `/dev/sda8`, either [unencrypted](/q/33697/175814) or [encrypted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemHowto3#Encrypted_Swap).

#### My previous advice (please use the above one instead)

Since raw devices (or raw `dm-crypt` devices) don't have UUIDs, you'll need to resort to other device identifiers. Kernel names (`/dev/sd*` and friends) aren't stable across boots, so your best bet is to find the entry inside `/dev/disk/by-id/`, that links to your intended encrypted swap partition. Those are stable enough in my experience (barring changes in the kernel or udev scripts).

Assuming that `/dev/sda8` is the intended place for the encrypted swap partition, you can find it's ID-based path(s) in the output of

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/* | grep sda8
```

or more elaborately with:

```
find -L /dev/disk/by-id -samefile /dev/sda8
```

You can use one of the results for the second column of the `crypttab` entry.

Comment: updated based on your answer.

Comment: On which partition do you want to have the encrypted swap partition?

Comment: `blkid` without `sudo` is useless ;)

Comment: @A.B. I did `sudo`.  @David: my swap in "Disks" & fdisk shows as sda8. And I did use the uuid's not the `/dev/sda*`. I used  `cat /dev/disk/by-uuid/` to get the uuid's and then `sudo bkid -U ****` to get the /dev/sda*

Comment: @user10853: Mounting that `dm-crypt` device and using it as swap space will sooner or later overwrite the header of the unencrypted swap partition, which holds the UUID. Overwriting with encrypted data will look like garbage and not announce a UUID to the system. You need to use a different method to identify your swap partition in `crypttab`.

Comment: I don't know what to do based on your comment. Isn't it possible to format the partition and recreate the swap for the system?

Comment: I understand it was convoluted and unnecessary. See my update.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have an error in your /etc/fstab file. You swap does not have mount point.

Change the line

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

to

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Comment: it doesn't appear in `swapon` does it require a reboot?
also according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Fstab_File_Configuration swap doesn't require a mount point.

Comment: You are right. Maybe a mistake in my own fstab. An other difference with mine, the mount right have defaults value instead of sw. Edited on my previous post. And yes you need to reboot after update your fstab (or sudo mount -a but I am not sure it's works for swap partition)

Comment: `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 swap swap defaults 0 0` ???

Comment: And why is `swap` a mount point and why is a swap partition mounted?

Comment: And no, you don't need a reboot!

Comment: didn't work. Updated post.

Comment: -1 The entry of seconds column in `fstab` is irrelevant for swap partitions. I have it set to `none` on my system and it works fine.